# Access a textview from another class file in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

I create a textView with id ReceivedCodeTxt in `activity_receive_code.xml` file and then i create a new kotlin file with name `SMSReceiver.kt` ... Now i want to set text for a textView in my `SMSReceiver.kt` file but i dont know how to access it and change text from another class.

```
    val bundle = intent!!.extras
    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            val pdusObj = bundle["pdus"] as Array<*>?
            for (i in pdusObj!!.indices) {
                val currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdusObj[i] as ByteArray)
                val phoneNumber = currentMessage.displayOriginatingAddress
                val message = currentMessage.displayMessageBody
                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: $phoneNumber; message: $message")
                // Show alert
                val toast = Toast.makeText(context,"senderNum: $phoneNumber, message: $message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver$e")
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using interfaces

create an interface in your SMSReceiver.kt class

```
class SMSReceiver.kt(val callback:ICallback) {
    interface ICallback{
        fun updateUI(value:String)
    }

    fun doSomething() {
       // your operations to perform some task. then call this
       callback.updateUI(/*Pass your data which you want to set to your textview*/ "")
    }
}


class ActivityReceive: SMSReciever.ICallback {

    override fun updateUI(value:String) {
        //set the data which you got from SMSReceiver class
        textview.text = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help dude but it doesn't work for me and also i can't pass my data to another class